# Get list of containers/services of docker-compose from inside a container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices, consul, registrator

There is a smart way to get the list of services (or containers) of docker-compose files from inside of a container.

I would prefer not to using volumes, or passing statically the compose-file to container and  parse it or pass a list with these infromations from environment variable.

One perfect result is given by `docker-compose config --service`,
that returns the list of all services of compose but I don't know how to pass it to my container from the host.

(I would like get the list of all containers that they compose my application so I can monitor which go up and down with using **registrator** and **consul**).

Comment: Isn't the consul API enough? You can query by service name

Comment: if a container not goes up, i will never know nothing about it , is right?
so i wish have a list of all container that compose my application..i don't want querying for a specific service.
Maybe i can do that with consul..but i don't know how.
Thanks.

Comment: @user2972221 Did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: This post is old now, but wouldn't mounting the docker socket work just fine for this?

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the instruction:

1. Install yq on your machine. for instance, if your operating system is macOS/OSX `brew install yq`.
2. Then run one of these commands: `docker-compose config | yq '.services[]|key'` or `docker compose config | yq '.services[]|key'`.

you will find the list of all available services.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow 2 space in your `docker-compose` for defining services, you can get list of services by following command

```
docker-compose config  |grep -E '^  [a-zA-Z_-]+'
```